# Azure AD login to web application fails after logout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure-active-directory

I'm working on an old ASP.net MVC application that runs on .net Framework 4.8.
The web app used to have a custom login which is now being replaced by Azure AD authentication.

I managed to set it up to a point where I can Log in to the Application using Azure AD. However, once I log out of the Application, I can't log in again until I restart the debugger. Interestingly, the first time I try to re-log in, the microsoft login page sends many seperate requests in quick succession before failing.

Here is my setup in startup.cs:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    //added for troubleshooting
    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    ConfigureAuth(app);
}
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions(){
    CookieName = "blargh",
});

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azure:ClientId"],
    Authority = $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azure:Instance"]}{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azure:TenantId"]}",
    RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azure:RedirectUri"],
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azure:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
    ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azure:ClientSecret"],
    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
    Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true
    },
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        SecurityTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            using (var LoginService = new LoginService())
            {
                var identity = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

                var emailClaim = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;

                //omitted - some DB mapping things

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }
    },
});
```

and here is my Signout Logic:

```
public ActionResult Signout()
        {
            try
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
                    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                Session.Abandon();

                var cookie = new HttpCookie("blargh")
                {
                    Expires = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                };
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                var redirectUri = Url.Action("Index", "Rapportierung", null, Request.Url.Scheme);
                var logoutUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azure:Instance"]
                    + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azure:TenantId"]
                    + "/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri="
                    + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azure:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

                return Redirect(logoutUrl);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //omitted - Error handling
            }
        }
```

I have tried all kinds of little tweaks, like setting ValidateIssuer = true in the TokenValidationParameters, manually invalidating the cookie (as seen in the "blargh" cookie - still in the code), changing the redirect URL around, adding/removing the trailing /signin-oidc and many other things.
I have also tried clearing all cookie data in the browser, didn't help. The behaviour also stays the same if I switch to a different browser - once I have logged out in any browser, the login error occurs in all others as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm grasping at straws.
Best regards

Comment: Thank you for your time - I've read through the issue, seems to be an entirely different problem to me, more concerned with the redirect - in my case, it's the actual re-login that doesn't work. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @C0res4w Check this [SO thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77958534/implement-authentication-using-azure-ad-azure-identity-for-asp-net-mvc-app/77966347#77966347).

Comment: @Dasari Kamali thank you, I am looking into it to see if I can get it to work :)

Comment: @Dasari Kamali I copied the code in the answer you linked and I run into the same issue - my best guess at this point is that it has something to do with leftover cookies (or similar) from the old login code interfering somehow. I think I will try to hollow out the codebase some more to see if I can resolve the issue that way, but won't get back to it until monday. Thank you again!

Comment: Can you share your index.razor?

Answer (score 0):

*I successfully signed out using the code below in an ASP.NET web application 4.8, utilizing openid and profile.*

**Code :**

***Startup.Auth.cs :***

```cs
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Owin;

namespace WebApplication58
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        private static string aadInstance = EnsureTrailingSlash(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"]);
        private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
        private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
        private static string authority = aadInstance + tenantId + "/v2.0";

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                    Scope = "openid profile",

                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                        {
                            string name = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("name").Value;
                            context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name, string.Empty));
                            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }

        private static string EnsureTrailingSlash(string value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                value = string.Empty;
            }

            if (!value.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                return value + "/";
            }

            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

***AccountController.cs :***

```cs
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;

namespace WebApplication58.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public void SignIn()
        {
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
        }

        public void SignOut()
        {
            string callbackUrl = Url.Action("SignOutCallback", "Account", routeValues: null, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }

        public ActionResult SignOutCallback()
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

***_Layout.cshtml :***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
            @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" title="Toggle navigation" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
                </ul>
                 @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

***index.cshtml :***

```html
<main>
    <section class="row" aria-labelledby="aspnetTitle">
        <h1 id="title">Hello World</h1>
    </section>
</main>
```

***SignOutCallback.cshtml :***

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sign Out";
}

<main aria-labelledby="title">
    <h2 id="title">@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
    <p class="text-success">You have successfully signed out.</p>
</main>
```

I granted permissions to **openid** and **profile** in the Azure Portal, as shown below.

[image]

**Output :**

I ran the above project, and it redirected me to the Sign-in page, where I chose my account as shown below:

[image]

The output appeared in my browser with my account, and I clicked on the **Sign Out** button to sign out, as shown below:

[image]

It redirected me to select my account for signing out, as shown below:

[image]

*I successfully signed out, as shown below.*

[image]